# Converting a plain LINQ C# query into LINQ extension methods

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

I have this Linq C# query in my code:

```
   var res = from i in context.Instrument
        join g in context.FtpServerGroup on i.FtpServerGroupId equals g.Id
        join f in context.FtpServer on g.Id equals f.FtpServerGroupId
        where i.Deleted && f.NetAddress == netaddress
       select i;
```

I need to translate it to another syntax (LINQ extension methods), used by .NET core, here an example not related to the previous query:

```
context.Instrument.Where(w => !w.Deleted).Include(x => x.FtpServerGroup).ThenInclude(x => x.FtpServers).FirstAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

My question is, I couldn't find a way to convert the first query (a triple join) into the other syntax. Any advice on how to find some documentation or how to do it?

Comment: A simple trick is often to look at your generated exe with [IlSpy](http://ilspy.net/), disabling everything in View->Options->Decompiler

Comment: Note that some things are much easier to do in LINQ "syntax" than in functional syntax.

Comment: Joins in a LINQ query means that some relations are missing. Why join in the query instead of adding an `Instrupent.Group` property? You could simply load the required instruments with `where i.Group.Server.NetAddress=x`

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. It makes warking with ORM's simpler though. If you have to perform 3 joins, it would be easier to just write the appropriate SQL statement

Comment: I'm with @PanagiotisKanavos It's much better to use **navigation properties** than plain joins. Also, `Include` / `ThenInclude` pattern **can** be used with query syntax (or mixed query syntax), so the question makes no sense.

Comment: Wait, you already have these properties? Why don't you `.Include()` them then? Remove the joins and just write `from in in context.Instrument.Include(x => x.FtpServerGroup).ThenInclude(x => x.FtpServers)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With power of resharper:

```
var res =context.Instrument.Join(context.FtpServerGroup, i => i.FtpServerGroupId, g => g.Id, (i, g) => new {i, g})
                .Join(context.FtpServer, @t => g.Id, f => f.FtpServerGroupId, (@t, f) => new {@t, f})
                .Where(@t => i.Deleted && f.NetAddress == netaddress)
                .Select(@t => i);
```

Comment: If you check the second snippet, the classes already have the appropriate navigation properties and the joins simply aren't needed. The OP could have used the query syntax, or a `.Where(@i => i.Deleted && i.FtpServerGroup.FtpServer.NetAddress == netaddress)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, I can agree with you, but question is not about logic, it's just about syntax. So, I made simple transform :)

Comment: That's the point. No joins are needed at all because the navigation properties are already there

Answer (score 2):

Jon Skeet has a nice [cheat sheet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/) (scroll down) for translating *query syntax* into *method syntax*.

Your query translates to:

```
var res = context.Instrument.Join(context.FtpServerGroup, i => i.FtpServerGroupId, g => g.Id, (i,g) => new {i,g})
                 .Join(context.FtpServer, x => x.g.Id, f => f.FtpServerGroupId, (f, x) => new {f, x.g, x.i})
                 .Where(x => x.i.Deleted && x.f.NetAddress == netaddress)
                 .Select(x => x.i);
```

Comment: Jon Skeet? the master himself? brilliant

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini the master would tell you to use relations instead of joins. Why aren't there any relations between Instrument, FtpServerGroup and FtpServer ?

Comment: there are! if you look carefully FtpServer and Instrument tables have both FtpServerGroupId which points to the Id field of the third table FtpServerGroup

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini why did you use joins at all then? Why the question?

Comment: This at least works which cannot be said to the currently accepted answer - "with power of resharper" does not event compile.

Comment: @IvanStoev it does here! And it works as expected too (which is very different from just a "it compiles")

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Really? with things like `@t => g.Id`? Not with normal VS C# compiler.

Comment: @IvanStoev VS2015 here, .NET 4.6.1, Resharper 2016.3

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini It might be some Resharper specific trick. But your question is not tagged with `resharper`, and aslo Resharper is not a standard VS component, so the answer does not work in general.

Comment: @IvanStoev works for me and I'm happy with that

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini My point is that it's not helpful for future readers, in contrast with Rene's answer. But your question is duplicate anyway, I already marked it and think to stop here. Take care.